# Simultaneously receive and process lots of data in Python web service

Tags: python, web-services, asynchronous

*I'm reforming a more concise version of my question here. Got flagged for being too broad.*

I'm looking for a way, either native python or a framework, which will allow me to do the following:

- Publish a webservice which an end customer can call like any other standard webservice (using curl, postman, requests, etc.)

  - This webservice will be accepting gigabytes (perhaps 10s of GB) of data *per call*.
- While this data is being transmitted, I'd like to break it into chunks and spin off separate threads and/or processes to simultaneously work with it (my processing is complex but each chunk will be independent and self-contained)

  - Doing this will allow my logic to be running in parallel with the data upload across the internet, and avoid wasting all that time while the data is just being transmitted
  - It will also prevent the gigabytes/10s GB to be put all into RAM before my logic even begins.

---

**Original Question:**

I'm trying to build a web service (in Python) which can accept potentially tens of gigabytes of data and process this data. I don't want this to be completely received and built into an in-memory object before passing to my logic as a) this will use a ton of memory, and b) the processing will be pretty slow and I'd love to have a processing thread working on chunks of the data while the rest of the data is being received asynchronously.

I believe I need some sort of streaming solution for this but I'm having trouble finding any Python solution to handle this case. Most things I've found are about streaming the output (not an issue for me). Also it seems like wsgi has issues by design with a data streaming solution.

Is there a best practice for this sort of issue which I'm missing? And/or, is there a solution that I haven't found?

**Edit:** Since a couple of people asked, here's an example of the sort of data I'd be looking at. Basically I'm working with lists of sentences, which may be millions of sentences long. But each sentence (or group of sentences, for ease) is a separate processing task. Originally I had planned on receiving this as a json array like:

```
{"sentences: [
    "here's a sentence",
    "here's another sentence",
    "I'm also a sentence"
    ]
}
```

For this modification I'm thinking it would just be newline delimited sentences, since I don't really need the json structure. So in my head, my solution would be; I get a constant stream of characters, and whenever I get a newline character, I'd split off the previous sentence and pass it to a worker thread or threadpool to do my processing. I could also do in groups of many sentences to avoid having a ton of threads going at once. But the main thing is, while the main thread is getting this character stream, it is splitting off tasks periodically so other threads can start the processing.

**Second Edit:** I've had a few thoughts on how to process the data. I can't give tons of specific details as it's proprietary, but I could either store the sentences as they come in into ElasticSearch or some other database, and have an async process working on that data, or (ideally) I'd just work with the sentences (in batches) in memory. Order is important, and also not dropping any sentences is important. The inputs will be coming from customers over the internet though, so that's why I'm trying to avoid a message queue like process, so there's not the overhead of a new call for each sentence.

Ideally, the customer of the webservice doesn't have to do anything particularly special other than do the normal POST request with a gigantic body, and all this special logic is server-side. My customers won't be expert software engineers so while a webservice call is perfectly within their wheelhouse, handling a more complex message queue process or something along those lines isn't something I want to impose on them.

Comment: what kind of data? when dealing with lots of input, you may want to break the collection of data from its processing and further output. Celery/kombu may be something worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks for the new information. Here are some questions to maybe try to help you a little further. Can you share a little bit more about the processing? How do you consume the processed data: is it stored, or just passed on into some other process? Do you need to store intermediate results? Is order important? Is it important to not drop any sentence, at least for gains in processing time?

Comment: added more clarifications @WillMonge

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I clarified the question.

Comment: Hi austin, unfortunately best practices questions are the subject of opinion, and opinion-based questions are off-topic. Check out the [help] for more info on what kinds of questions are good ones to ask and which ones to avoid asking here.

Comment: Well I'm not so much asking for a best practice opinion as much as any solution to the problem. I'm just hoping there's a normal/standard approach that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 2):

*Unless you share a little more of the type of data, processing or what other constraints your problem has, it's going to be very difficult to provide more tailored advice than maybe pointing you to a couple resources.*

... Here is my attempt, hope it helps!

It seems like what you need is the following:

- A **message passing system** vs **streaming system** in order to deliver/receive the data
- Optionally, an **asynchronous task queue** to fire up different processing tasks on the data
- or even a **custom data processing pipeline system**

---

**Messaging vs Streaming**

Examples: [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html), [Kombu](https://kombu.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/introduction.html) (per @abolotnov's comment), [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/intro) (and [python](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage.html) [ports](https://pykafka.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)), [Faust](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html)

The main differences between messaging and streaming can vary on the system/definition/who you ask, but in general:
 - *messaging*: a "simple" system that will take care of sending/receiving single messages between two processes
 - *streaming* adds functionality like the ability to "replay", send mini-batches of groups of messages, process rolling windows, etc.

Messaging systems may implement as well *broadcasting* (send message to all receivers) and *publish/subscribe scenarios*, that would come handy if you don't want your *publisher* (creator of data) to keep track of who to send the data to (*subscribers*), or alternatively your subscribers to keep track who and when to go and get the data from.

---

**Asynchronous task queue**

Examples: [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html), [RQ](https://nvie.com/posts/introducing-rq/), [Taskmaster](https://github.com/dcramer/taskmaster)

This will basically help you assign a set of tasks that may be the smaller chunks of the main processing you are intending to do, and then make sure these tasks get performed whenever new data pops up.

---

**Custom Data Processing Systems**

I mainly have one in mind: [Dask](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/) ([official tutorial repo](https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial))

This is a system very much created for what seems to me you have in your hands. Basically large amounts of information emerging from some source (that may or not be fully under your control), that need to flow through a set of processing steps in order to be consumable by some other process (or stored).

Dask is kind of a combination of the previous, in that you define a computation graph (or *task graph*) with data sources and computation nodes that connect and some may depend on other nodes. Later, and dependent on the system you deploy it on, you can specify for sync or different types of async in which the tasks will be able to be executed, but keeping this run-time implementation detail separate from the actual tasks to be performed. This means, you could deploy on your computer, but later decide to deploy the same pipeline on a cluster, and you would only need to change the "settings" of this run-time implementation.

[image: Dask system]

Additionally, Dask basically imitates numpy / pandas / pyspark or whatever data processing framework you may be already using, so the syntax will be (almost in every case) virtually the same.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions! yeah many of these are things I'd been looking into. I've added an example of my use case to the question, lmk if that's helpful

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I added some questions to the original question